# php round after last decimal number

Tags: php

I want to convert numbers like below in php

```
EX1: 0.00004123456 => 0.00004 
EX2: 0.000000004123456 => 0.000000004
EX3: 2.04123456 => 2.04
EX4: 2.44123456 => 2.4
```

I did not get results from the `round()` and more solutions

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to trim the number to its first non-zero digit? That is to say: 2.123 should be trimmed to 2.1, 15.0004756981321 should be trimmed to 15.0004, and so on?

Comment: Your question is not clear, How many decimal places do you want to display? where is your code? this may help?: `$num = round(0.00004123456, 6); echo number_format($num, 6);`

Comment: Please supply us some logic for why you want the results you show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a regex.

```
function trimToFirst($number) {
    // this is done to handle the cases of scientific notation
    // which can mess up the logic with very small or very large
    // numbers
    $strNum = sprintf('%f',$number);
    preg_match('/^-?\d+\.?\d*?([1-9].*?|0$)/',$strNum,$matches);
    
    if(empty($matches)) {
        return $number;
    } else {
        return (float)$matches[0];
    }
}

$numArr = [15, -7.130, 2.07014430, 0.00004123456, 0.0123456, 2.04123456, 2.44123456, .051, 0, -0, 0.000000];

foreach($numArr as $originalNumber) {
    $number = trimToFirst($originalNumber);
    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        // convert the number to a string format without scientific notation
        // and trim trailing zeroes
        echo rtrim(sprintf('%f', $number), '0');
    } else {
        // an integer, leave it as it is
        echo $number;
    }
    
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
15
-7.1
2.07
0.00004
0.01
2.04
2.4
0.05
0
0
0
```

Test it [here](https://onlinephp.io/c/2dcee).

---

**Explanation**

The regular expression which was used functions like this (as explained in [this regex101.com snippet](https://regex101.com/r/tHk9h5/2) ):

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `-` matches the dash character
- `?` matches the previous dash between zero and one times. This is done to handle cases when there are both positive and negative integers
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
- `\.` matches the decimal point
- `?` matches the previous decimal point between zero and one times. This is used to handle cases when there are integers and decimal numbers
- `\d` as before, this matches a digit
- *? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `(` and `)` are used to denote our capturing group and all the possible alternatives
- `[1-9].*?` - this is the first alternative. We're matching all the digits that can come after a decimal point, which are not zero
- `0$` - this is the second alternative. It's for handling cases when a number is a zero only number

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it as we would manually. Convert to string. Find a `.` and then the first non `0` char. `substr` then turn to number back.

```
<?php


$number = 0.0001432323;
$number2 = 14.323232;
$number3 = -6.098;
$number4 = -6.09;
$number5 = 12;


function rounder($number)
{
    $str = (string) $number;
    $index_dot = strpos($str, ".");
    if ($index_dot === false) {
        return $number;
    }

    // find first non zero after the dot_index
    $index_first_non_zero = false;
    for ($i = $index_dot + 1; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str[$i] != "0") {
            $index_first_non_zero = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($index_first_non_zero === false) {
        return $number;
    }
    return (float) substr($number, 0, $index_first_non_zero + 1);
}

echo rounder($number) . "\n";
echo rounder($number2) . "\n";
echo rounder($number3) . "\n";
echo rounder($number4) . "\n";
echo rounder($number5) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
0.0001
14.3
-6.09
-6.09
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function my_number($number)
{
    [$first,$second]=explode(".", (string) $number);
    
    $second=substr(
        $second,
        0,
        strpos(
            $second,
            substr(trim($second, "0"), 0, 1)
        )+1
    );
    
    return "$first.$second";
}
```